# Error when trying to add counter_cache to a self-join rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, self-join, counter-cache

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base 
    belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Product', :foreign_key => :parent_id
    has_many :children, :class_name => 'Product', :foreign_key => :parent_id
```

I am trying to add a counter cache to the `:children` column. I have tried the following:

```
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Product', :foreign_key => :parent_id
has_many :children, :class_name => 'Product', :foreign_key => :parent_id, counter_cache: true
```

and also:

```
has_many :children, :class_name => 'Product', :foreign_key => :parent_id, counter_cache: :children_count
```

When I run `Product.reset_counters(foo.id, :children)`

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `counter_cache_column' for nil:NilClass
```

Am I not understanding something fundamental about counter_cache or self-joins? Information about this is scarce and doesn't apply to this type of self-join.

Comment: just to make sure, `foo` is an instance of Product?

Comment: Could you share your schema for this table?

Comment: @Michael Gorman foo is an instance of product, yes.

Comment: @stef -   
`create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text    "main"
    t.text    "sub"
    t.text    "service"
    t.text    "master_format"
    t.integer "parent_id"
    t.string  "permalink"
  end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the counter cash should be on the belongs to like

```
class Child  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product, counter_cache: true
...
```

not on the has many in

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Product', :foreign_key => :parent_id
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Product', :foreign_key => :parent_id
```

but the database column should still be on the product

read through 4.1.2.3 at this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) for more info

Comment: oops! I meant this:
Changing it to this:  
`belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Product', :foreign_key => :parent_id, counter_cache: true
 has_many :children, :class_name => 'Product', :foreign_key => :parent_id`  
And running `Product.reset_counters(1, :children)`  
Yields this error:  
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "products_count" of relation "products" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "products" SET "products_count" = 7 WHERE "products"....`

Comment: I caught my :true column typo. I corrected it above.

Comment: does the parent table have a column for the `counter_cache`? if it does use that name instead of `true`,  if it doesn't you will need to a column in the parent table that is named `products_count`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was confusing myself with the self-join issue. [This article helped also](http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2016/02/05/proper-counter-cache-migrations-in-rails/). Having added the correct column, I am able to run the update.